# jquery trigger event only once on static and dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to trigger only one click on specific element that can be on page load time or added dynamically in the future. Some code

This code work just fine for elements that are rendered on load time but wont bind the click event to new elements dynamically added

```
$(".message-actions .accept").one("click", function(e){
    console.log("accept");
});
```

In the other hand if i do it this way, it will bind the event to new elements but don't unbind the event so if i click it again it will print the same console log

```
$("body").on("click", ".message-actions .accept", function(e){
    console.log("decline");
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

At last if i do it in this other way it will only fire the event in the first element i click even if there is more than one loaded or added after.

```
$("body").one("click", ".message-actions .accept", function(e){
    console.log("decline");
});
```

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: i already test that suppose this code $("#someelement").append("<div class='message-actions accept'>click</div>"); $(".message-actions .accept").one("click", function(e){
    console.log("accept");
}); it will add the event on every element existent

Comment: Just a tip for second test: The inverse of `on` is `off`, not `unbind`. But wouldn't do any difference, as the event is attached to the `body` as a delegated event, so doing `off` on the clicked element wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can add data to the element that remembers whether the handler has run before:

```
$("body").on("click", ".message-actions .accept", function() {
    if (!$(this).data("run-once")) {
        console.log("decline");
        $(this).data("run-once", true); // Remember that we ran already on this element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
 var handleClick = function () {
     // do your work
     alert("decline");

     // unbind
     $("body").off("click", ".message-actions .accept", handleClick);
 };

 $("body").on("click", ".message-actions .accept", handleClick);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v5bcog4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this, if it suits your situation : http://jsfiddle.net/hu4fp5qs/1/

```
$("body").on("click",".message-actions .accept",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("accept").addClass("decline");
    alert("Declined");
});
```

On click remove class `accept` and add class `decline`.

This will help you in styling both the cases differently so that you can distinguish between them.

```
.accept{
    background-color:green;
}

.decline{
    background-color:red;
}
```