# Trigger function with keydown only once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of messages on my page that are triggered by a keydown event once people start typing in a textarea. However, I can't figure out how to trigger it only once. Since people are typing longer responses, the function runs every time a key is pressed :/

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', function() {
        $('.three').delay(1000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.four').delay(2500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.five').delay(7500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.6').delay(12500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.7').delay(17500).fadeIn(1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery trigger event only once on static and dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576221/jquery-trigger-event-only-once-on-static-and-dynamic-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "on" use "one". This handles the event only once.

```
$(function() {
        $(document).one('keydown', function() {
        $('.three').delay(1000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.four').delay(2500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.five').delay(7500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.6').delay(12500).fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('.7').delay(17500).fadeIn(1500);
    });
});
```

Here's the reference: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Wow, I thought you were just being sarcastic because it seemed too simple. Amazing, thanks!!